# SQL Getting multiple rows from a single row

Tags: sql, plsql, rows, multiple-columns, unpivot

I need to accomplish the following :

I have a table with multiple column (c1, c2, c3, c4 ... cn).

I want a query that would return multiple rows in the following fashion (r1 r2 .. rx are the rows in the original table) :

```
r1c1 r1c2 r1c3
r1c4 r1c5 r1c6
...
r1cn-2 r1cn-1 r1cn

r2c1 r2c2 r2c3
r2c4 r2c5 r2c6
...
r2cn-2 r2cn-1 r2cn

...

rxc1 rxc2 rxc3
rxc4 rxc5 rxc6
...
rxcn-2 rxn-1 rxcn
```

I know I can use unions and repeat basically the same query n times, but I need to use that query in a web based reporting system that I have no control over and the query is to big for the maximum number of characters allowed in queries.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you !

EDIT : FYI I'm building a report in a report tool I can't change using a database I can't change. So using custom functions/procedures is not a solution. It has to be a PL-SQL query.

To be more specific, i need to have multiple rows from the original row, lets say row 1 is

```
a b c d e f h i j
```

and row 2 is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

then I would get the following table with 3 columns :

```
a b c
d e f 
h i j
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Try to implement it as a PL-SQL Function. There, you can build the algorithm you need. You can get the column names of the table by querying the database metadata and cross it to your row data.

Comment: Seems a bit unclear on what you are trying to achieve, do you need to return the column's value concatenated to the column's name all on one line for the same row ?
*edit:* as in
col1 col2 col3
x       y      z
a      b      c
and you wish to print as:
xcol1 ycol2 zcol3 (first row)
acol1 bcol2 ccol3 (second row)
?

Comment: So you're basically trying to word-wrap the columns in your table?  That sounds a lot more like a UI presentation issue than a data issue to me.  Anyway, maybe the easiest way to do this would be to first flatten everthing down to a single column, then clump those into short rows.

Comment: Hi, please see edits.  Than you

Comment: If you can't change the database, you can't use a PL/SQL (which implies you want to create a stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

So number 1, if you have a set number of columns in the original table that is divisible by 3, you can just do that many UNION ALL.

Your only other options are pivot or a pointer, neither of which is going to be any better.

Answer (score 0):

The simple case when `n` is divisible by `3` just use `rownum` and `union`:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
   SELECT rownum as rn,1 as tNum, c1 as s1,c2 as s2,c3 as s3 FROM T
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rownum as rn,2 as tNum, c4 as s1,c5 as s2,c6 as s3 FROM T
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rownum as rn,3 as tNum, c7 as s1,c8 as s2,c9 as s3 FROM T
)
SELECT s1,s2,s3 FROM T1 
ORDER BY rn,tNum
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da3b2f/2)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm trying to avoid since in the real situation I have 10 instead of 3 and 400 columns, so I end up with 40 unions and my query is too long for the app.